# Django drop down list dependant on model?

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to make a drop down list dependent on a model. For example my app has an organization model, when a user is created an organization is set for them. Organizations can have stores. When a logged in user accesses this drop down list, I want to list all the stores that are associated with the organization that the user is set to. What is the best way to do this?

models.py

```
class Org(models.Model):

  name = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=100)
  client_id = models.IntegerField()
  default_store = models.OneToOneField('Store',
    on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
    null=True,blank=True,
    related_name='+')

  def __str__(self):
    return self.name

class Store(models.Model):

  name = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=100)
  org = models.ForeignKey('Org', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  store_id = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)

  def __str__(self):
    return self.name


class Profile(models.Model):
  user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  org = models.ForeignKey('Org', 
    on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
    null=True, blank=True)

  def __str__(self):
    return self.user.username

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_or_update_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
  if created:
    Profile.objects.create(user=instance)
  instance.profile.save()
```

I would like to use this drop down list as part of the bootstrap nav bar where I have other drop down lists (associated). Here is the section of the nav bar code where I would like to use it. I know it won't fit exactly as I have below but this is an example of how I am making a different drop down list

```
            <div class="btn-group">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                Reports
              </button>
              <div class="dropdown-menu">
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'something' %}">Store_a1</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'something' %}">Store_a2</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'something' %}">Store_a3</a>

              </div>
            </div>
```

The page loads an iframe url where the store_id is passed in as a query parameter currently the store_id of the "default_store" is being passed. I'm thinking I need a variable for something like "selected_store" or something alone those lines? When the user clicks one of the stores on the drop down I would like the store_id of the selected store to be passed to the query param in the iframe url and refresh the page.

Thanks

Comment: Can you share the form where you want the filtered select and your models

Comment: Where is the user -> organisation relationship?

Comment: Sorry forgot to include that, just edited question again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your models you should be able to do something like this in your template to loop over all stores for a user

```
{% for store in request.user.profile.org.store_set.all %}
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'something' store_id=store.id %}">{{ store }}</a>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I think I may be having an issue accessing the store model. Does the below look like it should work? I would like to display the store name.

              {% for name in request.user.profile.org.store.all %}
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'something' store_id=store.id %}">{{ store.name }}</a>
              {% endfor %}

Comment: Actually I am going to need to access the store id with store.id instead of passing it to a query param in the url. Is there a way to "set" the store.id value by clicking the url?